# Are numbers at specific position in String?

Tags: vba

I just want to know if it is possible to check if there are numbers at a specific Position in a String

```vb
Sub test()

Dim a As String
a = "TestTestTest12"

'If (the 13th and the 14th positon are numbers) Then ...

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at the `Mid$` function.

Comment: Man I can't believe how many people are on the `VBA` tag just ready to help! Which is awesome :)

Comment: We all use VBA at work.

Comment: @Felix Can I have any feedbacks on my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57693429/11167163) . At Least if your issue is solved, May I ask you to Accept the Answer ? [Click here to see How to Accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Kindest Regards

Comment: @Felix If this issue is solved May I ask you to accept one answer? Click [here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```
Function IsNumberAtPosition(s As String, pos As Integer) As Boolean
  IsNumberAtPosition = IsNumeric(Mid(s, pos, 1))
End Function
```

Usage:

```
IsNumberAtPosition("TestTestTest12", 13)
```

Comment: Why don't you wrap this in a `For` loop from start of string to `Len(str)`, and you get a +1 from me

Comment: If you have a lot of positions to test, your performance could benefit from taking the string to test, put that in an 'character' array (VBA doesn't gave that type, technically it would be an array of 1-character strings), then test the array element for IsNumeric.This way, you would avoid looping over the string for every position you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

This is some code I had lying around to check the entire string, just thought I'd share, but you already have a better answer if you truly only want to check a specific portion.

```
Sub test()

my_string = "TestTestTest12"

Dim buff() As String
ReDim buff(Len(my_string) - 1)
For i = 1 To Len(my_string)
    buff(i - 1) = Mid$(my_string, i, 1)
    char = buff(i - 1)
    MsgBox char
    If IsNumeric(char) = True Then
        MsgBox char & " = Number"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If it helped, feel free to up-vote. I cast votes more then most, but why not? I up-vote and down-vote at will. I wasn't sure your use case, maybe this will help, maybe other answers will be better.

Comment: I do wonder why you allocate this string array, one element per original character. It does not seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: This answer work but this is not the best way .. You will use so much CPU

Comment: As @GSerg pointed out, there's much unnecessary code in there. The whole `buff` and `char` allocation/assignment can be reduced to `If IsNumeric(Mid$(my_string, i, 1)) = True`

Answer (score 0):

I think for almost any scenario the @EyIM answer suffices. I do however also like the @FreeSoftwareServers train of thought. Let me elaborate: as soon as you're talking about a position, an array feels like the natural thing. You want to treat the string as if it were an array. I do, anyway. So just as an alternative, and combining the answers already given, that could look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyStringArray() As String
Dim str As String

'run example
Sub Test()
    str = "TestTestTest12"
    MyStringArray = StringToArray(str)
    Debug.Print IsPositionNumeric(MyStringArray, 12)
    Debug.Print IsPositionNumeric(MyStringArray, 13)
    Debug.Print IsPositionNumeric(MyStringArray, 14)
End Sub

'return if character at position p in array arr is numeric
Function IsPositionNumeric(ByRef arr() As String, p As Integer) As Boolean
    IsPositionNumeric = IsNumeric(arr(p - 1)) '- 1 because string position is 1-based
End Function

'take string s and make it into array
Function StringToArray(ByRef s As String) As String()

    'define temp array
    Dim tmpArray() As String

    'set dimension of array to match string length
    ReDim tmpArray(Len(s))

    'assign each character in string s to array
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        tmpArray(i - 1) = Mid$(s, i, 1) 'remember that (by default), arrays are 0-bound, so - 1
    Next i

    StringToArray = tmpArray

End Function
```

This allows you to access your string as if it were an array, like a poor man's version of `ToCharArray()` in .Net. Granted, it may be total overkill. For one, it does an 'expensive' `Mid(string, position, length)` for every character, albeit just once. After that you just retrieve an element from an array, which is faster. So there is a balance between the number of positions you want to test and the length of the strings to test.

Answer (score -1):

Use regex:
/(\d+)/g
match and get the positions.

Comment: This strikes me as more of a comment then an answer.

Comment: It also uses the javascript `//` syntax which VB does not have.

Comment: @GSerg lol as if you cannot see how this the \d+ expression is represented in VB. Sometimes you need to use some search skills, not just copy&paste.